# Conditional counting of late payments monthly, including reset to zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following structure:

```
   EOM        ID     Principal       Pay_plan  cum_Payments
2019-12-31  AY4525  25000.000000    796.000000  936.000000
2020-01-31  AY4525  25000.000000    1592.000000 936.000000
2020-02-29  AY4525  25000.000000    2388.000000 936.000000
2020-03-31  AY4525  25000.000000    3184.000000 3184.00000
2020-04-30  AY4525  25000.000000    3980.000000 3980.00000
2020-05-31  AY4525  25000.000000    4776.000000 3980.00000
2020-06-30  AY4525  25000.000000    5572.000000 3980.00000
2020-04-30  KD4525  35000.000000    500.000000  500.000000
2020-05-31  KD4525  35000.000000    1000.000000 1000.00000
2020-06-30  KD4525  35000.000000    1500.000000 1000.00000
2020-07-31  KD4525  35000.000000    2000.000000 2500.00000
```

So I have a cumulative payment plan and cumulative payments for unique client IDs per month. Now I want to add a column which starts counting months that the client is late with payments, hence when pay_plan > cum_payments:

```
   EOM        ID     Principal       Pay_plan  cum_Payments  months_Late
2019-12-31  AY4525  25000.000000    796.000000  936.000000       0
2020-01-31  AY4525  25000.000000    1592.000000 936.000000       1
2020-02-29  AY4525  25000.000000    2388.000000 936.000000       2
2020-03-31  AY4525  25000.000000    3184.000000 3184.00000       0
2020-04-30  AY4525  25000.000000    3980.000000 3980.00000       0
2020-05-31  AY4525  25000.000000    4776.000000 3980.00000       1
2020-06-30  AY4525  25000.000000    5572.000000 3980.00000       2
2020-04-30  KD4525  35000.000000    500.000000  500.000000       0
2020-05-31  KD4525  35000.000000    1000.000000 1000.00000       0
2020-06-30  KD4525  35000.000000    1500.000000 1000.00000       1
2020-07-31  KD4525  35000.000000    2000.000000 2500.00000       0
```

The counter must be reset when pay_plan = cum_payments again. I have tried numerous ways of doing this with OVER(), but not found a solid solution. Anyone got an idea how to solve this?

Comment: . . What happens if someone makes a partial payment?  Say, if the row for 3/31 were 2000, rather than 3184?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  The islands are when the cumulative amount is less than the planned amount.   So, you can use a cumulative sum to define the islands and then `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when cum_payments >= pay_plan then 0
             else row_number() over (partition by id, grp order by eom) - 1
        end) as months_late
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when cum_payments >= pay_plan then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id order by eom) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7d66f40a6582823e058e53de4b1591e1) is a db<>fiddle.

You can handle the situation where the first payment is late by using:

```
select t.*,
       (case when cum_payments >= pay_plan then 0
             else row_number() over (partition by id, grp order by eom) - 1 +
                  (case when min(eom) over (partition by id) = min(eom) over (partition by id, grp) and
                             first_value(cum_payments) over (partition by id, grp order by eom) < first_value(pay_plan) over (partition by id, grp order by eom)
                        then 1 else 0
                   end)
        end) as months_late
from (select t.*,
             SUM(case when cum_payments >= pay_plan then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id order by eom) as grp
      from t
     ) t
```

I actually left this logic out of the above, because it seems inelegant.  There might be a better solution, but it does not readily occur to me.  [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5c2d990864502505155441ee1c22ac06) is the revised db<>fiddle.

Comment: Works fine as long as the first payment is not late, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=feb040a4662e9da2761aeae3adcf6b0b

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your logic correct, Months_late value for your last row should be 0 and if it is correct, you can use this below logic to achieve your requirement-

[Demo Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=66e25155272565b310724c6817c656e3)

> Let cum_Payments will always **increase or same** per day for a specific ID

```
SELECT *,
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM your_table B 
    WHERE B.cum_Payments = A.cum_Payments 
    AND B.EOM < A.EOM
    AND B.ID = A.ID
) Months_late 
FROM your_table A
ORDER BY ID,EOM
```

This following query will return the exact result as you are looking for. It is true that the query is bit heavy for a table with huge data but it is acceptable if you have one time use of this query. In case or more use, you can think about creating a view for improving query execution performance.

[Demo2 Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5221426a107c182ac01d241c767b0793)

```
SELECT *,
(
    SELECT count(1) FROM your_table b
    WHERE b.id = a.id AND b.eom <= a.eom
    AND b.eom >
    (
        ISNULL
        (
            (
                SELECT MAX(eom) FROM your_table c
                WHERE c.id = a.id AND (c.pay_plan - c.cum_payments) = 0
                AND c.eom <= a.eom
            )
            ,        
            (
                SELECT MIN(eom) FROM your_table d
                WHERE d.id = a.id
            ) 
        ) 
    )
)
FROM your_table a
ORDER BY id, eom
```

Comment: This would do the job, but it is very heavy to run on a large table (as in my case).

Comment: Can you please check the modified code here - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5221426a107c182ac01d241c767b0793 its giving exact your output. Yes its heavy but better to have an option at least :)